# SwipeRefreshLayout no muestra mi RecyclerView apenas la agrego al XML

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, recyclerview

Tengo un problema con un SwipeRefreshLayout, lo quiero implementar para poder realizar la función de Pull to refresh en una vista que contiene un RecyclerView, el problema es que cuando agrego el SwipeRefreshLayout y ejecuto mi app el RecyclerView ya no me muestra nada, se me muestra en blanco completamente, este es mi archivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="com.seccion.yugioh.ui.inicio.InicioCartasItemFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".ui.inicio.InicioCartasItemFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_inicio_cartas_item" />

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

No entiendo cual es el problema, simplemente estoy agregando el SwipeRefresh para poder recargar mi RecyclerView cuando el usuario tire de la vista pero una vez se agrega ya no se ve nada en el RecyclerView.

Se supone que la lista debe mostrar una lista de cartas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando ejecuto mi aplicacion ya con el SwipeRefresh no se muestra nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es mi clase donde cargo ese RecyclerView:

```
public class InicioCartasItemFragment extends Fragment {

    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    //Declaramos como variable global el recyclerView
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    //Declaramos como variable global nuestro adaptador
    private MyInicioCartasItemRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    //Creamos una lista gobal de nuestra respuesta del servidor que contiene el modelo de nuestro json
    private List<ResponseCartas> cartasList;
    //Creamos una instancia a nuestra clase ViewModel que nos permitira recuperar la informacion y enviarla al adapter
    private CartasViewModel cartasViewModel;

    public InicioCartasItemFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Inicializamos nuestra clase ViewModel
        cartasViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(CartasViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio_cartas_item_list, container, false);
        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;

            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }
            adapter = new MyInicioCartasItemRecyclerViewAdapter(cartasList, getActivity());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            loadCartas();
        }

        return view;
    }

    //En este metodo debemos mandar a llamar al metodo de getListaCartas que se encuentra en nuestra clase ViewModel
    //a este metodo le pasaremos un observador que nos permitira pasar los datos una vez cargados a nuestro adaptador
    private void loadCartas() {
        cartasViewModel.getListaCartas().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<ResponseCartas>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<ResponseCartas> responseCartas) {
                //a la lista que creamos en esta clase debemos igualarla a la lista que noes devuelve como respuesta nuestro servidor
                cartasList = responseCartas;
                //Una vez que rescuperamos la lista de cartas de servidor la enviamos a un metodo dentro de nuestra clase adapter
                adapter.setData(cartasList);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL problema estaba en mi onCreateView, estaba instanciando de diferente forma el RecyclerView como vista principal dentro de mi XML, lo he cambiado por esto y ha funcionado:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tienda_cartas_item_list, container, false);
        swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_view_tienda);

        // Set the adapter
        Context context = view.getContext();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_tienda);
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }
        //Al adapter debemos de pasarle la nueva lista que creamos y el contexto de la clase con getActivity
        adapter = new MyTiendaCartasItemRecyclerViewAdapter(tiendaCartas, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        loadCartasTienda();

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        return view;
    }
```